# How to hard reset a Samsung Galaxy GT-i5800?

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-apollo

My Samsung Galaxy GT-i5800 has had the wrong pass entered too many times, and now it's not opening up. So how do I do a factory reset on it, since all the workarounds I've tried (phoning it, mashing keys, putting 'null' as the password') haven't worked?

Comment: A few questions: You don't get a button pop up in the bottom-right allowing you to enter your Google password to unlock the phone?  Or a timeout before you can try again?  Do you mean the i5800 rather than 15800?  Have you rebooted the device?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the 15800. When I enter my Google account, it comes up with an error, despite me entering it correctly. It's permanently locked. I have rebooted it.

Comment: the GT-15800 is the galaxy apollo; GT-i5800 is the galaxy 3

Comment: @RyanConrad According to Samsung the [Galaxy Apollo](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/android/GT-I5800DKAXEU) and some [Galaxy Minis](http://www.samsung.com/it/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/smartphones/GT-I5800CWAOPT) are i5800 and the [Galaxy 3](http://www.samsung.com/sg/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphone/android-os/GT-I5801DKAXSO/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail) is the i5801, all three just variants of the same thing.  15800 is just a misreading, that's why I always lowercase the `i`.

Answer (score 4):

Reboot into recovery, where you can select the option to factory reset (scroll up/down with the volume keys, use power to select).

Two ways to get into recovery:

1. Install the Android SDK on your computer and run `adb reboot recovery`
2. Power off the phone, hold down both volume buttons and (while holding) click the power button.  Release the volume buttons when recovery appears.