# Trying to factory reset, but it's not listed at all as an option

Tags: factory-reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hard reset a Samsung Galaxy GT-i5800?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18663/how-to-hard-reset-a-samsung-galaxy-gt-i5800)

I'm using a GT-I5800L (firmware 2.1-update 1) and I'm trying to do a factory reset to see if I can get the Wi-Fi working again. I've done a factory reset on the phone in the past but it's no longer listed as an option.

When I go to Settings -> SD Card and Phone Storage, this is all that I see:

**External SD card**

Total Space

1.84GB

Available Space

1.47GB

Unmount SD card

Unmount SD card for safe removal

Format SD card

Format (erase) the SD card

---

Internal phone storage

Available space

80.7MB

At the bottom there used to be a factory reset option... Any ideas? I'm not overly computer smart either :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite often asked question -- so please see the "Linked" and "Related" sections for more answers.

A good place to check for answers concerning factory reset is always hard-reset.com. At [Samsung I5800 Galaxy 3 Android hard reset](http://www.hard-reset.com/samsung-i5800-galaxy-3-android-hard-reset.html), they write how it can be done for your phone. Basically, it involves the following steps:

### Using hardware buttons only

1. Press MIDDLE of the <kbd>VOLUME</kbd> + <kbd>MENU</kbd> (middle key) + <kbd>POWER ON</kbd> for 1-2 sec
2. Release <kbd>Power</kbd>. Recovery menu appears.
3. Select Wipe Data/ Factory reset with <kbd>volume down</kbd>, then press <kbd>MENU</kbd>
4. select Yes - delete all user...
5. press <kbd>MENU</kbd> or <kbd>POWER</kbd> button

They further recommend: *to hard reset i5800 Galaxy 3 battery must be fully 100% charged.*

### Alternative approach

As you still can turn on your phone normally, there's a second option available:

1. open up yout telephone app (dialer)
2. dial *2767*3855#
3. follow the instructions

This is not a real phone call, but rather a "magic number" (shortcut to system functions).

Last word: Be aware that with a factory-reset all your manually installed apps and all your data on internal/phone memory are lost, so backup what you need before! I guess you knew that, but just in case ;)